# Sprite sometimes doesn't load in Phaser game

Tags: reactjs, sprite, phaser-framework

Sometimes the game starts without waiting for all the assets to load. This happens most often with the `spaceStation` which is the largest sprite at 3372x700 px. When the game first boots, the `spaceStation` isn't loaded. But if you leave the game then come back to it without refreshing the page, it will be loaded the second time. I am using the Phaser game engine with the IonPhaser wrapper for React.

The game is hosted here so you can see what I mean: https://seanhetzel.github.io/star-runner/#/

Here is my code for the `spaceStation` sprite:

```
import spaceStation from "../assets/space-station-sprite-sheet.png";

// other stuff...

preload: function() {

// other stuff...

    const spaceStationImg = new Image();
    spaceStationImg.onload = () => {
      this.textures.addSpriteSheet("spaceStation", spaceStationImg, {
        frameWidth: 3372,
        frameHeight: 700
      });
    };
    spaceStationImg.src = spaceStation;

// other stuff...

}

// other stuff...

create: function() {

// other stuff...

    const config = {
        key: "lights",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("spaceStation", {
          start: 0,
          end: 6
        }),
        frameRate: 3,
        repeat: -1
     };

     this.anims.create(config);

     this.spaceStation = this.impact.add
       .sprite(1686, 350, "spaceStation")
       .play("lights")
       .setDepth(1);

// other stuff...
}
```

Am I not loading it correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Phaser 3 Loader should use the imported sprite instead of pointing directly to the relative path in the `preload()` function when using react.

```
import spaceStation from "../assets/space-station-sprite-sheet.png";

// other stuff...

this.load.spritesheet(
            'spaceStation',
            spaceStation, // <-- not '../assets/space-station-sprite-sheet.png'
            {
              frameWidth:3372,
              frameHeight:700
            }
          );
```

Now it’s getting the sprite from import spaceStation from "../assets/space-station-sprite-sheet.png"; import instead of directly pointing to the relative path and using the Phaser 3 Loader.